# Can NextFlow resolve nested include-modules?

Tags: nextflow

Versions:

```
NextFlow: 23.05.0-edge
OpenJDK VM: 11.0.1+13
Groovy: 3.0.17
```

In DSL2, does NextFlow resolve nested include-modules?  Eg, say I have this file structure:

```
- workflow.nf
  modules
    - utils
      - main.nf ............. defines addAll()
    - filters
      - main.nf ............. defines aggregateFactorsOfFive(), includes/uses addAll()
```

Then in `workflow.nf`, we have:

```
include { aggregateFactorsOfFive, addAll } from './modules/filters'
...
process p1 {
  input: val(x0), val(x1)
  output: val(y)

  script:
    y0 = aggregateFactorsOfFive(x0, x1)
    y1 = aggregateFactorsOfFive(10*x0, 10*x1)
    y = addAll(y0, y1)
}
```

Can we import `addAll` like this?  If not, then should `modules/utils` be included in both `workflow.nf` and `filters/main.nf`?  And if we do that, does NextFlow avoid naming conflicts in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Functions, processes and workflows can be imported/included using the [`include`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-inclusion) keyword. Because the `addAll` function was imported into the `filters` module, it can also be imported *from* the `filters` module. We can test this for example:

Contents of `workflow.nf`:

```
include { aggregateFactorsOfFive; addAll } from './modules/filters'


process p1 {

    input:
    tuple val(x0), val(x1)

    output:
    val(y)

    exec:
    y0 = aggregateFactorsOfFive(x0, x1)
    y1 = aggregateFactorsOfFive(10*x0, 10*x1)
    y = addAll([y0, y1])
}

workflow {

    input_ch = Channel.of( [1, 5], [2, 10], [3, 15] )

    p1( input_ch )

    p1.out.view()
}
```

Contents of `modules/utils/main.nf`:

```
def addAll(List<Integer> numbers) {

    return numbers.sum()
}
```

Contents of `modules/filters/main.nf`:

```
include { addAll } from '../utils'


def aggregateFactorsOfFive(int start, int end) {

    def factors = []
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (i % 5 != 0) {
            continue
        }

        factors.add(i)
    }

    return addAll(factors)
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run workflow.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `workflow.nf` [focused_sanger] DSL2 - revision: 8139d7fbe2
executor >  local (3)
[85/91e070] process > p1 (2) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
275
2280
1035
```

If you're worried about potential conflicts, use the `as` keyword to specify a [`module alias`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-aliases). Note that if the `addAll` function above was actually a Nextflow [process](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#process), the fully qualified process name can also be used with a [process selector](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#config-process-selectors) in your `nextflow.config`. Process selectors using a fully qualified process name take priority over selectors with the same (unqualified) process name.